# Powershell script to find all backups on all drives and print file path, file name, and file size

Tags: powershell

I found scripts that all circle around the answer I need but I cannot figure out how to combine them.

Here is a script to find all the backups on all drives but it moves them; I just want to print the details (to file preferably).

```
foreach ($server in Get-Content c:\scripts\sl.txt){
foreach ($root in 'c$','d$','e$','f$'){
cmd /c dir "\\$server\$root\*.bak" /B /S /A-D |%{
 Move-Item $_  -destination C:\users\Scripts
}
}
}
```

And I found others that will print all files with particular extensions found in a single drive.

```
$Extensions = @(".bak",".csv",".txt")
Foreach ( $Extension in $Extensions )
{
 [System.IO.Directory]::EnumerateFiles("C:\","*$Extension","AllDirectories")
}
```

I am having trouble combining the two and under tons of pressure. Please help!

Comment: Try changing the Move-Item line to be: $_.Fullname | Out-File c:\temp\filename.txt -append     (Your server should have a c:\temp directory or you will likely get an error - this also assumes you're running this on one server, your question doesn't make it clear whether this is for multiple servers)

Comment: I tried this but it just sat for around 10 minutes with nothing writing to the file. I reduced the directories that were listed to just the C$ drive in the $root list but same results. The first part of the code actually looks at a file to get a serverlist but I only created a sl.txt file that lists the server it was running on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That first example uses cmd to call dir which is unnecessary since Get-ChildItem can do a directory listing.  `Get-ChildItem` actually returns much more information and in an object format which is very usable in further scripting.  There are even aliases (`Get-Help alias`) for `Get-ChildItem`: `dir`, `ls` and `gci`.  (Save these for commandline, scripts should use the long form for readability).

The second example is using some kind of .Net roundabout method of enumerating properties of the file objects.  MUCH easier to use dot notation, or `Select-Object -Property` directly with the powershell objects.  Use 'Get-Member' to see the list of properties and methods of an object.  e.g. `gci | gm`

```
PS M:\> $file = gci c:\windows\notepad.exe

PS M:\> $file.DirectoryName
C:\windows
```

Or

```
PS M:\> (gci c:\windows\notepad.exe).DirectoryName
C:\windows
```

If you wanted to do a oneliner, set $server beforehand or insert actual name, and change the output file name each time:

`"C$","D$","E$","F$" | %{gci "\\$server\$_\*.bak" -recurse} | %{export-csv -notypeinformation -append c:\temp\filelist.csv}`

Another thing to consider would be modifying the objects returned by 'Get-ChildItem' to add a property to hold the 'server' property.  Since the DirectoryName property already includes the root drive letter, you could then output all servers and drives .bak file lists into one file.

Bottom Line, use this modified version of what arco444 wrote:

```
function List-Backups {
    foreach ($server in Get-Content c:\scripts\serverlist.txt){
        foreach ($root in 'c','d','e','f'){
            $outfile = "C:\Temp\FileList-$server-$root.csv"
            Get-ChildItem "\\$server\$root"+'$'+"\*.bak" | 
             Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name ServerName –Value $server |
             export-csv $outfile -NoTypeInformation -Append
        }
    }
}
```

This gives you a CSV file with all the files **remaining as objects**.  You can then do what you want with the CSV.

`import-csv c:\temp\filelist.csv | select Name, DirectoryName`

Later, you can create function(s) to pull information from the text files output by this function.

Comment: Thank you! I must have a setting wrong or a library not loaded because when I run this at the powershell command prompt it does nothing. It's the same thing with the modified version of arco444's code. I appreciate you taking the time for the in depth explanation!

Comment: @BeckyDBA, You are welcome.  Key thing in all of that is `Get-Help` and `Get-Member` are your friends, and keep data in objects until time to display them.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below:

```
foreach ($server in Get-Content c:\scripts\sl.txt){
    foreach ($root in 'c$','d$','e$','f$'){
        $files = Get-ChildItem \\$server\$root\*.bak 
        foreach($f in $files) {
          Write-Output "$($f.directoryname) $($f.name) $($f.length)" | Tee-Object -Append C:\output.log
        }
    }
}
```

For each root volume you can use the `Get-ChildItem` command to get a list of `*.bak` files. This will return a list of `FileInfo` objects which contain properties such as `length` (size), `name`, `LastWriteTime` etc...

You can access these properties by looping over the list and accessing using the `.` notation. Use `Write-Output` to print the results to the screen, you can optionally pipe to `Tee-Object` to print to both the screen and a file.

Comment: I'm getting an error. I'm researching it now but it is: Tee-Object : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Append'.

Comment: It's because I'm on an old version of PoSh. Argh!

Comment: Haha, yeah looks like it needs v3 or up. You can just remove that bit, or use `Out-File` in its place to write to a file, but then the results won't print to screen. It was really only for illustration purposes

Comment: Can I just get the results printed to the screen? I tried to adjust but removed the bar and everything after and it doesn't do anything. Just brings up another prompt. Then I try to replace Tee-Object with Output-File and it still does not populate the file. I'm not so worried about results to file at this time.

Comment: Removing `| Tee-Object -Append C:\output.log` should print to screen - I don't know why that would open a new prompt